# Google Drive shared file URL is not working for exchange user in firefox

Tags: java

I shared a file using google drive API which is accessible in chrome but not in Firefox. Can somebody tell me why it is not accessible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may have to be authenticated to view the file? Login on google drive on firefox and see what happens after

Comment: Thanks for your help, but after sharing the file to another user, I don't think that logging in to the owners google drive account is a solution for the problem.